# Sinon Stub function in another function

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, stub, enzyme

So am I testing React app with Mocha+Enzyme+Sinon. I am trying to test a function with if statement in which there is a call to another function. 
My goal is to enter the if statement, but stub the second function call. Here is the code:

```
    onSearchChange = ({value}) => {
    const port = '/search-users?search_q=';
    const path = [port, value].join('');

    if (value.length >= 2 && value.length <= 5) {
        this.getUsers(path, (array) => {
            this.setState({ suggestions: fromJS(array) })
        });
    }
};
```

So I want to enter if statement, but not call getUsers() function. How can I do that?
I am spying onSearchChange() like this:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<ContentEditor />);
const spy = sinon.spy(wrapper.instance(), 'onSearchChange');
```

Looking forward to hear, thanks!

Comment: You should never mock or stub methods on the object you test. In your case I assume that `getUser` makes some ajax request, so stub the thing that make the request instead of manipulating your tested class.

Answer (score 0):

i think we can stub the function inside the component you are testing this way.

```
sinon.stub(ContentEditor.prototype, 'getUsers')
```

and test it like

```
expect(ContentEditor.prototype.getUsers.called).to.be.true;
```